# SQL - Query between two tables (top and bottom)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I´m having difficulties creating a query between 2 tables.

Table Pilot

```
Id (Primary Key)
Name
```

Table Season

```
Year (Primary key)
Pilot_id (Foreign Key)
```

I just want to make a query to catch the first and last year of each pilot

Comment: You want to `join` the tables on Pilot ID, then `select max(year), min(year), id` and `group by id`

Comment: If you can't get this to work, show us what you attempted so we have a better idea of what you need help on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically this:

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,max(s.year),min(s.year)
FROM Pilot t
INNER JOIN Season s
 ON(t.id = s.pilot_id)
GROUP BY t.id,t.name
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what i was trying to do! =) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
Select Id, Name,
    (Select Min(Year) from Season Where Pilot_Id = Id) as FirstYear,
    (Select Max(Year) from Season Where Pilot_Id = Id) as LastYear
  from Pilot
```